# Archiving layer in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, archiving

We have some layer which is creating data every day. On every 3 months or if data is more than 100K geometry we need to archive the layer.

How can we archive this in GeoServer and any best practice how realworld is doing it?

Comment: What do you mean for "archive"? Anyway GeoServer only publish your data through web-services. Your data are somewhere else (generally a geoDB like PostgreSQL/PostGis), so maybe the question isn't related to geoserver...

Comment: What is the data store for this layer? I'd agree that if using PostGIS you should set up a process to archive the back-end table vs. the geoserver layer